# Como selecionar N registros em um select no Oracle plSQL?

Tags: oracle, sql-select

Tenho 3 tbs , faço o seguinte pego o id da tb1 em comum com tb2 e tb3(id ), depois comparo se o campo 1 da tb1(LENGTH) é maior que o campo 1 da t2, nas tbs 1 e 2 existem vários ids da tb3, (é necessário percorrer as tbs 2 e 3 toda fazendo essa comparação) como são muitos registros demora muito, por isso gostaria de um select trazendo apenas alguns ids para fazer aos poucos..

Comment: No caso você deseja limitar o número de registros da consulta para 5?

Comment: tenho 3 tbs , faço o seguinte pego o id da tb1 em comum com tb2 e tb3(id ), depois comparo se o campo 1 da tb1(LENGTH)  é maior que  o campo 1  da t2, nas tbs 1 e 2  existem vários ids da tb3, (é necessário percorrer as tbs 2 e 3 toda fazendo essa comparação) como são muitos registros demora muito, por isso gostaria de um select trazendo apenas alguns ids para fazer aos poucos..

Comment: @JaniceCarvalho A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Isto?

```
select id from tabela a, tabela b where id=id fetch first 5 rows only
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Limit.sql).

Comment: Obrigada ,nesse caso não atende no 11g, é necessário percorrer a tb inteira fazendo comparações, daí pego o maior campo entre 3 tb, porém são muitos ids, então gostaria de compara de 50 em 50 por exemplo.